# Avoid duplicate requires clause in forward declaration of template?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I'm playing with the Concepts TS in a new project.  My question has to do with a seeming circular dependency I have between a struct template and an associated concept I want to create.  The specific logic of the concept is to check that a type argument to the concept is a specialization of the struct template.  Since I'd like the concept to be available for use inside the struct template, I apparently need to define the concept before the struct template, but then the logic of the concept needs to know about the struct template as well.  I have worked out something that will compile, by forward *declaring* the struct template `Vector`, then defining the concept `VectorSpecialization`, then finally *defining* the struct template `Vector`.  My specific question relates to the fact that I use a `requires` clause for the struct template; when I forward declare it, the compiler gives me an error unless I duplicate the full `requires` clause.  (See code below).

**My specific question is**: is there way to avoid the full duplication of the `requires` clause between the template's forward declaration and definition?  One possibility would be to factor out the logic of the `requires` clause into a common entity that both the declaration and definition could delegate to, which I suppose would address the DRY principle; but I'm curious if there's a higher-level structural decision I could have made here to avoid the need of even having a `requires` clause in both places, or if there's a more idiomatic way of using concepts for use cases like this that I could benefit from.  To re-iterate, the use case I'm speaking of is: writing a concept that will be used in a template, but the concept also needs to know about the template.

```c++
// Forward declare the struct template so that the concept can refer to it
// Note the need to repeat the 'requires' clause.  Can that repetition be
// be avoided?
template< typename T, size_t N > requires N > 1 struct Vector;

// compile-time overload set using template arg deduction to detect
// when the argument is a specialization of 'Vector'
template< typename NonVector >
    constexpr bool IsVectorSpecialization( NonVector && ) {
        return false;
}
template< typename T, size_t N >
constexpr bool IsVectorSpecialization( Vector<T, N> && ) {
    return true;
}

// The concept, which uses the above overloaded constexpr function
template< typename VectorCandidate >
concept bool VectorSpecialization_CV
        = IsVectorSpecialization( std::declval<VectorCandidate>() );

template< typename T, size_t N >
requires N > 1
struct Vector : std::array<T, N> {
    // Some function templates with VectorSpecialization parameters, e.g.
    //     T dot( VectorSpecialization const &other ) const;
    // ...
};
```

*(Note: Aside from the specific question, I'd also welcome discussion (in the comments, of course) about aspects of the Concepts TS design that bear on this question and/or solutions that people offer, since part of the reason I'm playing with the Concepts TS is to see how well it works in practice, to see if there's any useful feedback for the committee before full standardization.  For example, is there a tweak to the design of "Concepts Lite" that could remove the need to duplicate `requires` clauses like this?)*

Comment: There are a couple of issues with the sample code: (1) the concept is named `VectorSpecialization_CV` but elsewhere referred to as `VectorSpecialization`, (2) the definition ODR-uses `std::declval`, which is a no-no.

Comment: @Casey, would you mind elaborating on the `std::declval` being a no-no?  It was compiling for me, but that's because I wasn't yet instantiating the `dot` function template; once I added code to do so, the compiler (GCC) told me `error: call to non-constexpr function`, referring to the `std::declval<VectorCandidate>()` that you pointed to.  I can understand that error well enough.  But is there more to it than that, that you were referring to?

Comment: That's close enough ;) The standard explicitly forbids ODR-uses of `declval` ([declval]/2), since implementations only declare it. ODR-use in `constexpr` context is ill-formed for two reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the guarantees provided by constrained templates is that whenever a template specialization is named, the parameters must meet the constraints. See P121R0 §14.3 [temp.names]/8:

> When the *template-name* of a *simple-template-id* names a constrained non-function template or a constrained template *template-parameter*, but not a member template that is a member of an unknown specialization (14.7), and all *template-arguments* in the *simple-template-id* are non-dependent 14.6.2.4, the associated constraints of the constrained template shall be satisfied. (14.10.2).

In the context of your example, that means that e.g. it's ill-formed to name `Vector<int, 1>` even without instantiating it:

```
template< typename T, size_t N > requires N > 1 struct Vector;
using foo = Vector<int, 1>*;
// ill-formed: constraints not satisfied: '(N > 1)' evaluated to false
```

That guarantee could not be enforced if it was possible to declare a template without its associated constraints. The associated constraints are a critical part of the declaration.

This is even more apparent in the context of function templates, where otherwise identical function template declarations with different associated constraints declare overloads. For example:

```
template<typename T>
requires true
bool foo(T) { return true; }

template<typename>
constexpr bool always_false = false;

template<typename T>
requires always_false<T>
bool foo(T) { return false; }
```

This is a perfectly valid program that declares two overloaded function templates named `foo`, the second of which will never be selected by overload resolution. Again, the associated constraints are a salient feature of the declarations. It's as necessary to repeat the associated constraints at every declaration as it is to repeat the name of the template entity or the number and kinds of the parameters.

Concepts are the mechanism the language provides to manage this repetition: instead of repeating enormous constraint expressions over and over, we provide convenient names for them. `N > 1` is hardly onerous enough to be deserving of a named concept to save keystrokes, but [providing a single point of definition for the notion is clearly worthwhile](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QKhUedqBFBx0Tncf):

```
template< size_t N > concept bool VectorLength = N > 1;
template< typename T, VectorLength N > struct Vector;

template< typename >
constexpr bool IsVectorSpecialization = false;
template< typename T, size_t >
constexpr bool IsVectorSpecialization<Vector<T, N>> = true;

template< typename VC >
concept bool VectorSpecialization = IsVectorSpecialization<VC>;

template< typename T, VectorLength N >
struct Vector : std::array<T, N> {
    T dot( VectorSpecialization const& );
};
```

There's really no other choice for defining this kind of structure. The fact that concepts cannot be forward-declared is annoying at times, but I find that designs that have been decomposed into the linear structure necessary to avoid impossible-to-express cyclic dependencies are quite easy to understand.

Comment: `requires false` *"This is a perfectly valid program"*. Not really, as there are no valid specializations, see [temp#inst-17](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#inst-17)

Comment: @Jarod42 Fair enough - `always_false` to the rescue!